# How to set different opacity to bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, transparency, opacity

I'm using

```
.navbar-default {
z-index:99;
opacity:0.8;
}
```

and I want to set dropdown menu items to 0.9 opacity.

Tried many things but none succeded. For example:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
opacity:0.9 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
opacity:0.9 !important;
}

.open {
background: #fff !important;
opacity:0.9 !important;
}
```

To be more clear the idea es that everything in the menu gets the opacity of 0.8 except the opened dropdown menus. So I need a way of overriding the first rule (the one that sets 0.8 opacity)

Answer (score 0):

use `rgba` instead, if it did not work please leave a comment

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

check [demo here](https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/wrZbPK)

Comment: it seems using rgba values doesn't override opacity set in a parent class.

Comment: for me it seems to work (firefox). the dropdown is transparent.

Comment: Yes but did you set as well .navbar-default {opacity:0.8}                               Because if that is set and for example I want the opacity to be 1 in the drobdown with rgba it will display 0.8 opacity and not 1. Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: can you please fork the demo and update to the content to what you want to be able to understand and do what you need exactly. plz don't forget to send url

Comment: Okey here it is https://codepen.io/Snippet/pen/PJvaMP You may notice the second line of css is not in effect, and thats the problem. How can I override/set a different opacity to a children element without deleting the parent opacity line.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to change to use rgba in both .container {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2)
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

Comment: check the demo here again and mark as correct answer if it was helpful for you - https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/ZXNmaM